# Task.Faulted and Task.Exception

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Neither [TaskStatus Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Task.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN appear to state explicity:

Does `TasksStatus.Faulted` ALWAYS imply `Task.Exception != null` (and `TaskStatus != Faulted` always imply `Task.Exception == null`)?

Comment: just check how Task.Status is implemented at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,771e3c39534a4177,references. It's complex but more accurate.

Comment: Tks - the source is interesting.  There is internal ExceptionRecorded (with comment "The property formerly known as IsFaulted") - which checks for a recorded exception.  There is IsFaulted which checks (m_stateFlags & TASK_STATE_FAULTED) and Status which does exactly same check as IsFaulted.  So from code its less clear - it certainly not as simple IsFaulted checking for a recorded exception.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the documentation for [Task.IsFaulted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly states that:

> If IsFaulted is true, the task's Status is equal to Faulted, and its Exception property will be non-null.

The reference source code does list the as an almost certainly.  In `FinishStageTwo`, we see that the internal `m_state` is only set to faulted if exceptions were recorded:

```
  if (ExceptionRecorded)
  {
      completionState = TASK_STATE_FAULTED;
      ...
  }
  ...
  Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_stateFlags, m_stateFlags | completionState);
```

So the state will only be faulted if exceptions were recorded.

However, `Exception` getter does mention a possible race condition:

```
// Only return an exception in faulted state (skip manufactured exceptions)
// A "benevolent" race condition makes it possible to return null when IsFaulted is
// true (i.e., if IsFaulted is set just after the check to IsFaulted above).
```

This race condition will only occur if `IsFaulted` becomes true as `Exception` getter is running.

So the following code could fail if called while the task is executing:

```
 var ex = task.Exception;
 var faulted = task.IsFaulted;
 if (faulted)
     Assert.IsTrue(ex != null);
```

However the following will never fail:

```
 var faulted = task.IsFaulted;
 var ex = task.Exception;
 if (faulted)
     Assert.IsTrue(ex != null);
```

The first case will also never fail if you've already finished waiting for the task to complete.  That's probably why they labeled it as "benevolent" and left it in.  The amount of code that would be affected by it is pretty small.

Comment: duh should have looked there!

Comment: The code source as suggested by @qxg is not as convincing and clear cut as the doc at Task.IsFaulted makes it seem.